# exit child process, safely

Tags: linux, perl, exit

I trying to learn `fork` and this is a simple program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# PRGNAME.pl by Whom
#
#
use strict;
use warnings;

main(@ARGV);

sub main
{
    my @array = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6);
    while ( (my $t = pop @array) ) {
        if (! (my $pid = fork) ) {
                exit if ( $t == 2 );
                for(;;){}
        }
    }
    waitpid(-1, 0);
    message("This is the $PRGNAME exercise file.");
}

sub message
{
    my $m = shift or return;
    print("$m\n");
}

sub error
{
    my $e = shift || 'unkown error';
    print("$0: $e\n");
    exit 0;
}
```

But on the shell when I am trying: `ps -fu $LOGNAME | grep [f]ork`, I found:

```
  i59tib 28361     1   3 16:20:07 pts/34      6:07 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
  i59tib 28363     1   3 16:20:07 pts/34      6:07 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
  i59tib 28366     1   3 16:20:07 pts/34      6:07 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
  i59tib 28364     1   3 16:20:07 pts/34      6:07 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
  i59tib 28362     1   3 16:20:07 pts/34      6:08 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
```

Here one of the processes exited and also its parent while I comment this line `exit if ( $t == 2 );`

and run `ps -fu $LOGNAME | grep [f]ork` again, I found:

```
  i59tib   624   623   1 16:29:11 pts/34      0:04 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
  i59tib   629   623   1 16:29:11 pts/34      0:04 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
  i59tib   628   623   1 16:29:11 pts/34      0:04 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
  i59tib   625   623   1 16:29:11 pts/34      0:04 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
  i59tib   627   623   1 16:29:11 pts/34      0:04 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
  i59tib   626   623   1 16:29:11 pts/34      0:04 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
  i59tib   623  4766   0 16:29:11 pts/34      0:00 /usr/bin/perl ./fork.pl
```

How can I exit the child process without exiting the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I exit the child process without exiting the parent?

The parent exited because the parent reached the end of the program, so tell the parent to do something, anything!  For example,

```
1 while waitpid(-1, 0) > 0;
```

Comment: No, parent waits for all process because of `waitpid(-1, 0);` and I know this because I tested it. If you made the `exit` commented the parent will not exit till the children finish.

Comment: Please look carefully at the second `ps`

Comment: If you don't believe me, the test you posted that proves the opposite and the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid), then why did you bother asking?

Comment: I am asking about explicit exiting?

Comment: The parent will behave exactly the same no matter how the child exits. It doesn't matter if the `exit` system call is called as a result of Perl exiting `main` or if your child called Perl's `exit` or `POSIX::_exit`, or if the child died from a signal.

Comment: Yes, now I understand you, THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I exit the child process without exiting the parent?

try below program here Child dies before parent.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "i am about to fork\n";
my $pid = fork();
if($pid > 0) {
    my $i = 0;
    while($i<5) {
         print "PARENT--I will be keep on running\n";
         sleep(5);
         $i++;
    }
    print "PARENT-- I m about to dead\n";
} else {
    $i = 0;
    while($i <3) {
        print "CHILD-- I will be dead before than parent\n";
        #exit(0);   you can put exit like this also.
        sleep(2);
        $i++;
    }
    print "CHILD-- I m about to dead\n";
}
```

Below is the sample output.

```
i am about to fork
PARENT--I will be keep on running
CHILD-- I will be dead before than parent
CHILD-- I will be dead before than parent
CHILD-- I will be dead before than parent
PARENT--I will be keep on running
CHILD-- I m about to dead
PARENT--I will be keep on running
PARENT--I will be keep on running
PARENT--I will be keep on running
PARENT-- I m about to dead
```

You can exist with any supported signal also.You can get different signal list [here](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~alanjawi/cs449/code/shell/UnixSignals.htm). You can use the same sample code at loop too but make sure here that there will be one super parent and other will be their child.

please run this program to understand more about this. Always super-parent will get exited at the end no matter you use exit or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "i $$ am about to fork\n";
my @children_pids;
my $n = 3;
for my $i ( 0..($n-1) ) {
    my $pid = fork();
    if($pid > 0) {
        print "i m $$ child of".getppid()."\n";
        push @children_pids, $pid;
    } else {
        print "I $$ is about to dead. I am child of".getppid()."\n";
        exit();
    }
}
waitpid $_, 0 for @children_pids;
print "$$ is finished\n";
```

typical output at my system of above program is as below.

```
i 3919 am about to fork
i m 3919 child of3092
I 3920 is about to dead. I am child of3919
i m 3919 child of3092
i m 3919 child of3092
I 3921 is about to dead. I am child of3919
I 3922 is about to dead. I am child of3919
3919 is finished
```

Parent will wait all its child to get exit;then only it will exit.

Comment: Your program here use a normal exit, which doesn't make any abnormal behavior, but what if you explicitly issue `exit` subroutine ?

Comment: you can use exit also.I have commented it.Please check the next program to understand more about this.